# How to redirect mobile site users to a mobile layout

Tags: php, .htaccess

I can't find some solid information on what I'm specifically looking for, nor do I know the best method of doing this (in code or using HTACCESS); to redirect mobile users to `http://m.example.com`

I am looking to enable both mobile, and PC users to view our website in both devices, with a user-friendly layout to accommodate for both users.

Comment: THe common approach is to use JS to check the browser, then redirect. You could allow a redirect override via a link and storing it in a session, or only offer the redirect once.

Comment: The best approach is typically to use what's called [Responsive design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) and revolves around the idea of using @media to identify your styles for specific platforms. If you can use this over your current idea it would be prefered, since it avoids you creating two copies of your site. If you insist on redirecting might I suggest using [Mobile Detect](https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect).

Comment: Have you tried my solutions ([1] via .htaccess and [2] via PHP Sessions)?

Answer (score 0):

The solution without HTACCESS:

Best way is store the info about which layout is selected in Cookie.

```
if(isset($_GET["setMobile"])) {
  setcookie("m", $_GET["setMobile"], time()+(60*60*24*31), "/");
}
```

And then

```
if($_COOKIE["m"]) {
  /* MOBILE LAYOUT */
}
```

I thnk you do not even Need htaccess. You can create `index.php` in your subfolder `m.domain.com` and place there Cookie Definition.

```
setcookie("m", true, time()+(60*60*24*31), "/");
```

Comment: I think you may have missed the question, the question is about how to detect mobile users and redirect them.

Comment: I forgot so solve how to check if Desktop in `PHP` and after set Cookie.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution: A : To redirect mobile users to mobile layout**

Via .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^desktop
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-mobile|iemobile|iphone|ipod|#opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://m.example.com [L,R=302]
```

=====================

**Solution: B: Redirect mobile site users to mobile layout and from mobile to desktop**

Via PHP Session

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '?desktop=1' ?>">Go to Desktop version</a>

<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION['desktop'])) {
    $_SESSION['desktop'] = false;
}

if(isset($_GET['desktop']) && $_GET['desktop'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['desktop'] = true;
}

if(!$_SESSION['desktop']) {
    if ( !$detect->isMobile() ) {
      header('Location: http://m.example.com/');
    }
}
?>
```

On your mobile site, you can pass a get parameter of desktop=1. Normally, if the parameter is not passed, and if the session is not set, it's false. On false value of $_SESSION['desktop'], you continue your script so it redirects to mobile. But once the param is passed, it changes the session to true, and you block will not be executed, so the normal (desktop) content of the site will be visible.

Comment: Lets pretend you are mobile Viewer and you want to see Desktop Version. Is there any Chance to get that page?

Comment: in the footer of http://m.example.com, you can put the link `Go to Desktop Version` which will then redirect to http://www.example.com. That's what I generally do.

Comment: But remember, if you entry example.com, the htaccess will Redirect you again to m.example.com.

Comment: @M1K1O I have added `Solution B` to accomplish that.

Comment: It is almost the same as my solution, but why do you store the variable in `seesion`? If I come next day to a site where I previous set to be as desktop view, I must choice again. And, it has nothing to do with server side, but cleary with user side. So because is better to use `Cookies`.